# logical operators in vf pages

Tags: visualforce

I have a scenario in my vf page, where the date field in the page block table can be editable only if the present value in the field is greater than the todays date.

so for this i wrote the code as follows

```
<apex:outputField value="{!customerProduct.customerProduct.Product__r.mydate}">
                 <apex:inlineEditSupport event="ondblclick"  changedStyleClass="myBoldClass" resetFunction="resetInlineEdit" disabled="{!customerProduct.customerProduct.Product__r.mydate<TODAY()}"/>
                </apex:outputField>
```

it is getting saved, but on the page on page it is throwing an error. Please kindly tell me the proper way to use, disable in this scenario. Thanks in advacne

Comment: try this 
disabled="{!if(customerProduct.customerProduct.Product__r.mydate<TODAY()) true, false}" this may fix the issue

Comment: what error do you get on the page?

Comment: @anu that is identical to OP except for being unnecessarily more verbose.

Comment: We cannot help you if you do not provide the error message.